Get the count of hosts where package is not installed
I want to display the count of hosts/servers that do not have a given package installed  (example: "abc") in a Grafana dashboard with Postgres as data source.
Example table of a single server with "abc" package present which is displayed in Grafana:



Hostname
Package
version
Package_installed_on_server




server1
abc
10.0.1
true


server1
abc
10.0.2
false


server1
package2
3.1
true


server1
package3
4.1.1
true


server2
package2
3.1
true


server2
package3
4.1.1
true


server2
package4
10.0.1
true


Server3
package2
3.1
true


Server3
package3
4.1.1
true



For example, I have 10,000 servers and in 400 servers the package "abc" is not installed. Then Grafana should display the count of servers where no version of "abc" is present.
This is what I tried. With the above example the output should be 2 where package abc is not present. But I am not getting the output as expected (or 2).
SELECT count(*) 
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT hostname     
     FROM scanner_table     
     GROUP BY hostname     
     HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN package = 'abc' THEN 1 END) = 0 
) AS host_without_abc;

How to solve this?

The code looks correct and runs just fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/-Crf-Loo . The DISTINCT is superfluous by the way, as the hostname is per se distinct when you group by it.

Shouldn't you just test whether Package_installed_on_server is true in addition to filtering on the package name? (And remove the DISTINCT)

Simple, naive, slow, first implementation - count all hosts - count all hosts with abc package = hosts without abc package:
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT hostname  
    FROM scanner_table
  ) 
  EXCEPT
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT hostname  
    FROM scanner_table     
    WHERE package = 'abc'
  ) 
)

More mature solution: left join for the same hostname with selected package and count hostnames, where join is empty/null:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.hostname) 
FROM scanner_table AS a
LEFT JOIN scanner_table AS b
  ON a.hostname=b.hostname AND b.package = 'abc'
WHERE b.hostname IS NULL


Depending on undisclosed details, one or the other query is simpler / faster.
Setup
CREATE TABLE scanner_table (
  hostname text NOT NULL  -- !
, package text NOT NULL  -- !
, version text
, package_installed_on_server bool
);

INSERT INTO scanner_table VALUES
  ('server1', 'abc'     , '10.0.1', true)
, ('server1', 'abc'     , '10.0.2', false)
, ('server1', 'package2', '3.1'   , true)
, ('server1', 'package3', '4.1.1' , true)
, ('server2', 'package2', '3.1'   , true)
, ('server2', 'package3', '4.1.1' , true)
, ('server2', 'package4', '10.0.1', true)
, ('Server3', 'package2', '3.1'   , true)
, ('Server3', 'package3', '4.1.1' , true)
;

This multicolumn index helps all below queries (if table is vacuum'ed enough), some more some less;
CREATE INDEX scanner_table_hostname_package_idx ON scanner_table (hostname, package);

You should have a hostname table with one row per relevant host.
Consider creating one if you don't:
CREATE TABLE hostname (hostname text PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO hostname VALUES
  ('server1')
, ('server2')
, ('Server3')
;

Queries
Fastest if table hostname exists. (FASTEST overall.)
See:

Select rows which are not present in other table

SELECT count(*)
FROM  hostname h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM scanner_table s
   WHERE  s.hostname = h.hostname
   AND    s.package = 'abc'
   );

Fastest without table hostname and only few rows per hostname.
Similar to what you tried (which should actually work, inefficiently).
SELECT count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT FROM scanner_table  -- SELECT list can stay empty
   GROUP  BY hostname
   HAVING bool_and(package <> 'abc') -- assuming column package defined NOT NULL
   ) sub;

Emulating an index skip scan will be fastest without table hostname and many rows per hostname.
Needs the index to be fast. See:

SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT hostname, package
   FROM   scanner_table s
   ORDER  BY hostname, package <> 'abc'
   LIMIT  1
   )

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT s.hostname, s.package
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   scanner_table s ON s.hostname > c.hostname
   ORDER  BY s.hostname, s.package <> 'abc'
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT count(*)
FROM   cte
WHERE  package <> 'abc';

fiddle
The expression package <> 'abc' in ORDER BY sorts the package 'abc' on top. Why?

ORDER BY column, with specific notnull value LAST

If column package can be NULL, you need to do more for some queries.
